# What is difference between Restage and Restart in PCF

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

What is difference between Restage and Restart your application in Pivotal Cloud Foundary and when to pick one among this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The quotes below are from the 2.0 [documentation](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-0/devguide/deploy-apps/start-restart-restage.html).

#### Restart

> Restarting your application stops your application and restarts it with the already compiled droplet.

So if you haven't made any changes and don't need to re-compile the project, a `Restart` should be done.

#### Restage

> Restaging your application stops your application and restages it, by compiling a new droplet and starting it.

Restaging your app compiles a new droplet from your app without updating your app source. If you must update your app source, re-push your app.

#### Differences

The difference between the two is that `Restart` won't re-compile the project while `Restage` does.

Comment: So 'cf push' and 'cf restage' are similar

Comment: Similar in that they will both end up deploying the application. `cf push` won't re-build the application like `cf restage` does.

Comment: `cf push` send new app code bits to pcf. `cf restage` uses earler pushed code bits and recreates droplet by executing buildpack.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the above answer, to know when to **restart** and **restage** please find below the explanation from the Docs.

**When to Restart:**

> Restart your app to refresh the app’s environment after actions such
>   as binding a new service to the app or setting an environment variable
>   that **only** the app consumes.

**When to Restage:**

> Restage your app if you have changed the environment in a way that
>   affects your staging process, such as setting an environment variable
>   that the buildpack consumes. The staging process has access to
>   environment variables, so the environment can affect the contents of
>   the droplet.

Answer (score 1):

Restart simply use existing droplet to bounce  with out compiling.

Restage will compile and creates a new droplet to bounce.

If you have simple properties change then restart would be the best idea.